# unique_together does not prevent duplicate records

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models like this :

```
class Preference(models.Model):

    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25,decimal_places=15)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25,decimal_places=15)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=350,null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True,null=True)

class PrefenceOfUser(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        place_detail = models.ForeignKey(Preference, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
    
        class Meta:
            unique_together = ('user', 'place_detail',)
```

this is the json i post to my apiview :

```
 {
        "lat": "29.621142463088336",
        "lng": "52.520185499694527",
        "name":"cafesama1",
        "address":"streetn1",
        "type":"cafe"
       
    }
```

in views.py :

```
class PreferedLocationsOfUsers(APIView):
   
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PreferLocationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():

                location= Preference(**serializer.data)
                location.save()
                user_perefeces = PrefenceOfUser(user=request.user,place_detail=location)
                user_perefeces.save()
            return Response({'location saved'},status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

i want to prevent the user to save dublicated records in database but when  location object is saved  in PrefenceOfUser unique_together does not prevent dublicating. any idea why?

Comment: Have you run the migrations after adding the `unique_together`?

Comment: You are creating a new place every time. In this way, `place_detail` is different in each post request.

Comment: You should probably before saving the location of user, check if lang and latitude of user for latest record is the same, so he or she is not moving...

Comment: @ Jose Antonio Castro Castro i did the migration and it works but i got UNIQUE constraint failed error is there any way to get this in my code ?

Comment: then try to delete all your record in the database.maybe you have duplicate records.

Comment: I think the same as @amadousow. Probably you  already have duplicate records before run the migrations..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a migration issue as per the comments. Get rid of the duplicates, re-run the migration until you get no errors and you're fine.

However, I would turn this around as a model design problem. You shouldn't need to resort to manual constraints for this.

```py
    class Preference(models.Model):

        lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25,decimal_places=15)
        lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25,decimal_places=15)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)
        address = models.TextField(max_length=350,null=True)
        type = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True,null=True)
        users = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), blank=True)
```

This above code will have exactly the same implications as yours, is cleaner and more Djangoesque.

You can still access what you call `PrefenceOfUser` through `Preference.users.through`. If you plan to add more attributes to the selection (ie. when did user add their preference), you can just do:

```py
    class PrefenceOfUser(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        place_detail = models.ForeignKey(Preference, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        extra_field = models.WhateverField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

and change the `Preference.users` to

```py
models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), through=PrefenceOfUser)
```

which will still still ensure the uniqueness.

Comment: Very useful and helpful solution!tnx